# Mac crashed on reformat

Tags: macos, mac, crash, formatting

I was reformatting a corrupted flash drive on a Mac. So I do so, and it formats into the Mac's format. So I decide to change the setting to fat and format again. It crashes and and I have a computer only showing the white screen with the apple, and it constantly trying to boot up over and over.

Comment: Sounds like you reformatted the wrong drive

Comment: Wouldn't it warn me not to do that? Plus i reformatted the flash drive once, so unless it switched to the other drive on completion, it shouldn't have done that.

Comment: All I know is the act of reformatting the flash drive would not have touched your system drive

Comment: Well I know that it formatted the flash drive once, and then I changed the format to fat, so unless it switched the selected drive to the primary one after my first format (which would be stupid), it should not have touched it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 macs, both with either firewire or thunderbolt, then you start your dead mac in 'disk target mode'  You will then be able to examine contents of hard drive and see if was reformmated.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725

Comment: Wouldn't this also work with any other (possibly non-mac) second computer? If boot the crash Mac in disk target mode and connect it as a drive to a windows/BSd/linux based laptop?

Comment: Attaching a Mac in disk target mode to a Windows computer could be very dangerous, as Windows will not recognize the partitioning, and may want to reformat it.  It could also be rather dangerous on other Operating Systems because of way Apple has a very specific partitioning scheme.

Comment: Ah. Good points. I never ran into those since I had the apple partitioning scheme and HFS in my kernel, but I suspect that windows ships without those allowed bad things to happen when the wrong button is pressed.